# My cat brings mice ALIVE and it is becoming a problem

Tags: cats, mice

Here's the issue.
My cat bring mice into the house (we live in countryside and she brings forest mice), and she brings them almost always alive. It is becoming significant problem as she is "playing" with them, and injures them that way so while hiding from her they die and start decomposing inside the house (?!). If I am home, I try to take them out as soon as she brings them, but while we're at work she gets bored and brings home god knows how many. Yesterday we located 3 dead mice, one of which was about 2 weeks old dead and hiding in the most remote place of the house, and was smelling really, really bad(that is the only reason we managed to find it).
I tried putting collar with a bell on her hoping they would hear her and run away, it didn't help. Would declawing help, or what else can we do to stop her from doing this.

Comment: Please don't declaw, it's inhumane.

Comment: This is a problem to be dealth with, mice can have fleas, dead mice forgotten everywhere in the house is the perfect start for a fleas home invasion